# State not updating in SunEditor onChange event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, suneditor

#### version

- next: 12.0.7
- suneditor: 2.41.3
- suneditor-react: 3.3.1

```js
const SunEditor = dynamic(() => import("suneditor-react"), {
  ssr: false,
});
import "suneditor/dist/css/suneditor.min.css"; // Import Sun Editor's CSS File
```

```js
// states
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [content, setContent] = useState<string>("");
```

```js
useState(() => {
  console.log(toggle, content);
}, [toggle, content]);
```

```js
// render
return (
  <SunEditor
    onChange={(content) => {
      setToggle(!toggle);
      setContent(!content);
    }
  />
);
```

When I type the console panel always shows me that only `content` was changed, but `toggle` is not changed.

I really don't know what happens, I just want to set other states inside `SunEditor`'s `onChange` event, but I can't. Can anyone just explain to me how to fix this?

Comment: Does changing the `setToggle` call to `setToggle((value) => !value);` fix the issue?

Comment: @juliomalves Oh, that work! Thank you so much. But... it seem re-render/update twice because console panel log twice per toggle, but that's ok. Can you explain why this happen, why it should set state with return value in callback.

Comment: The `console.log(toggle, content)` might happen twice because both the `toggle` and `content` state variables are changed within `onChange`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a function inside the `setToggle` function to get the current state value and return the modified value for that state variable.

```js
<SunEditor
    onChange={(content) => {
        setToggle((value) => !value);
        setContent(content);
    }
/>
```

Due to the async nature of `setState`, passing in a function into the state setter instead of a value will give you a reliable way to get the component’s state. It's the recommended approach when setting state based on previous state.